# Website layout has suddenly changed in Chrome on widescreen monitors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, widescreen

Updated my website design last week and tested it on different browsers and devices – it's a portfolio site using Bootstrap - and all was good. I checked my website this morning on my widescreen monitor using chrome and the full-width images seemed to have been reduced in size leaving a margin on the right-hand side.

This anomaly is not showing up on different browsers or even on Chrome using a smaller screen!

The website is live at http://www.burnser.com/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add when I test this on Chrome from my local folder the site looks fine on my widescreen monitor. It's just when i upload that something seems to happen.

Comment: [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images themselves only have a native width of 1600px. If they should always be full screen, you should include `width: 100%;` to your CSS.

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>img, 
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail a>img, 
.thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply seemly, but there's no .carousel in my code.

Comment: If you inspect one of your images, the CSS in my answer is defined by Bootstrap. I just added the `width: 100%;` to it, which fixes the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It worked! Thanks a million seemly.